# AVR mega2560 printf() and fgetc() don't work

Tags: c, embedded, avr

I'm trying to learn about embedded programming, so I bought an arduino mega2560. I didn't really like the arduino IDE (Because it feels a little too basic and abstracted, at least for me :)) so I started programming it using pure C and the avr toolkit (avrdude and such). I'm trying to write a program that reads your name, and then blinks the LED for each character in your name.

The program's basic outline is:

1. Turn the LED pin to output mode
2. **printf() "Enter your name"
3. **Read the user's name using fgetc, realloc and such (I'm not using scanf() because scanf() with a buffer can cause a buffer overflow)
4. Blink the LED for each character in the user's name

The problems (Indicated by **) are that I can't see printf's output and fgetc asking for input. How to fix this?

Thanks!

Edit: Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

#ifndef STDIN
#define STDIN 0
#endif

int main(void) {
        char *name = (char *)malloc((int)NULL);
        char c;
        int cnt;
        int i;

        cnt = 1;

        DDRB |= (1 << DDB7);

        printf("Enter your name: ");

        while ((c = fgetc(STDIN)) != '\n') {
                name = (char *)realloc(name, cnt);
                strncat(name, &c, 1);

                cnt++;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < strlen(name); ++i) {
                PORTB |= (1 << PB7);
                _delay_ms(1000);
                PORTB &= ~(1 << PB7);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried. Your question lacks lots of specifics and implementation details.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs Do you mean adding the code? What more should I add?

Comment: Step 1: `char c;` --> `int c;` to properly save the 257 different return values of `fgetc()`.

Comment: `strncat(name, &c, 1);` is bad as `name` does not point to  a _string_.

Comment: Arduino programs normally use a serial port for input/output. Can you compile this code without errors or warnings? Do you have a library that implements `printf` and `fgetc`? Dynamic memory allocation can lead to problems on embedded systems.

Comment: @Bodo Yeah I got no errors. I included stdio.h which implements printf and fgetc

Comment: Not related to your question, but dynamic memory allocation and returning from `main()` are not really appropriate on your platform.  Returning from main in a standalone environment is implementation defined - your run-time environment may loop indefinitely, reset or just run-off into who knows where and exhibit undefined behaviour.

Comment: `(char *)malloc((int)NULL)` is nonsense. And using malloc on a MCU is senseless in the first place. [Why should I not use dynamic memory allocation in embedded systems?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/286121)

Comment: Please, explain what do you expect from your arduino (where are you printing, and how are you inputting the data) and what happens, instead.  I imagine you don't have a console terminal attached to your arduino, so where's the input expected, and where is your output supposed to be printed?

Comment: Passing a null pointer to `fgetc()` is unlikely to give you the results you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stdio library for MCUs where the `stdout`, `stdin` need not exist at all and where they do they are necessarily dependent on the hardware and available I/O and are design decisions of the project developer not the responsibility of the library designer.

Typically for an embedded library there will be a porting or "glue" layer to map the library to the hardware dependencies, and if you do not supply the necessary functions they will be linked to generic "do nothing" stubs.

The specific stub-function overrides you need to provide will depend of the toolchain and specifically the C library you are using. And the means by which you "install" them differs depending on the toolchain.  Some use "weak-links" that you simply provide overrides with the same signature, others use structures with function pointers to the low-level I/O functions.
For example if you are using [AVR Libc](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/), you simply need to provide a get-char / put-char functions use them in a `FILE` structure assigned ot the `stdin`, `stdout` streams as described in the [documentation](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdio.html).

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Output character to stdout device
static int std_putchar(char c, FILE *stream)
{
    ...
    return 0;
}

// Input character from stdin device
static int std_getchar(char c, FILE *stream)
{
    ...
    return rxchar ;
}

// Create stdio stream
static FILE stdio_stream = FDEV_SETUP_STREAM( std_putchar, std_getchar,
                                              _FDEV_SETUP_RW ) ;

int main(void)
{
    stdout = &stdio_stream ;
    stdin = &stdio_stream ;
    stderr = &stdio_stream ;

    printf( "System Start - hello\n") ;

    // Echo input
    for(;;)
    {
        putchar( getchar() ) ;
    }
}
```

You can implement the low level character I/O functions in any way you wish to suit your system, to use a UART, keypad, LCD display, debugger interface - whatever.

Answer (score 0):

1. `char *name = (char *)malloc((int)NULL);` this makes no sense at all. You basically allocated 0 bytes to name. Also do not cast malloc results.
2. On this micros **never** use `malloc` type dynamic allocation. It is not a PC computer and you need to forget many "large" computer stuff;
3. What is your STDIN on such a target?
4. What is your stdout on this micro?
5. `strncat(name, &c, 1);` it's weird. And it will not work as nono of your parameters are C strings. Do you know what the last parameter is?
6. `strlen` will not work as you do not pass C string.

> I didn't really like the arduino IDE (Because it feels a little too
> basic and abstracted, at least for me :))

I think at your level of knowledge it is the correct direction. Arduino is C++ + libraries and it is not "simple"

> Yeah I got no errors. I included stdio.h which implements printf and
> fgetc

Adding the header file does not sort the problem. You need to write some low-level functions to `stdio` functions start to work. `stdout` and `stdin` do not communicate via UART by default. Read some more: https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdio.html#ga4c04da4953607fa5fa4d3908fecde449

Comment: "Also do not cast malloc results." This is the hobbyist Arduino goo, so it's actually C++.

Comment: @Lundin he said that he is not using Arduino

Comment: Aren't those custom libs part of the Arduino libs? Or is it just something supplied by Atmel/Microchip?

Comment: @Lundin I believe,  avr-gcc is maintained by Microchip. But (because there is no OP or file system) they provide only stubs of the IO functions (same as ARM branch). You need to connect it to the real hardware

Comment: Well, 1. is no sense at all, doesn't mean it's UB or an error.... It initializes `NULL` into `name`, so it's good when it reaches `realloc()`.  On 2.  Why would he have `malloc` library implemented for that platform if he couldn't use it? Don't you think you are overreacting? shouldn't exist a `malloc` implementation, wouldnt he get a linker error at build time?  I'm a bit confused as I'm developing on embedded and what I see is that if you don't have some function available, then you get a linking error.

Comment: Because you have very limited reasource and this tiny memory will be instantly fragmented.

Answer (score 0):

Arduino `fgetc()` and `printf()` normally read and print from the serial port, which you must initialize to set a baudrate, parity, stop bits, and character size to operate (and you probably are not aware of this). This normally requires you to start a Serial Connection terminal emulation (and configure it with the same baudrate, parity, stop bits, and charsize) to observe Arduino's i/o.  then you load the software to the arduino, start your terminal emulation and press the reset button (to let the arduino boot again)

It's not clear were are you expecting your output to go, and you don't say anything about it, so I'm probably over presuming you have an incorrect idea of your environment, I can be wrong, but you have not mentioned any of the characteristics above (any of them configured incorrectly and you will see rubbish, or nothing at all).  Your arduino is not part of your computer, so don't expect it's output to go direct to open a popup window in your computer and show it.

I'm sorry of not detailing a bit more how to configure an arduino (and the pc to do what you want to do) but there are many videotutorials in youtube that show you how to do that.  There are very good tutorials from Ben Eater (just search for them) and plenty of projects (not trivial, many of them)

IMHO, you have oversimplified your target, and started with a far more complex project than you can just swallow in one shot.